# RxJS: delay for onNext with related events?

Tags: javascript, rxjs

Scenario: user can drag an item on the web page, and drop on other item(s). When user drags item onto another object, live feedback is shown to the user about what will happen if he drops item X on item Y.

When user start to drag data must be fetched from backend for current item and this might take 1-2 seconds.

So basically while this happens, we must show to the user some kind of loader, and wait before giving feedback, even though he already may have dragged item X onto item Y.

I'm using dragula library which has the following signature:

```
  dragula(dragulaConfig)
  .on('drag', function(el, source ) { /* do on drag */ })
  .on('cancel', function(el, container, source ) { /* do on cancel */ })
  .on('drop', function(el, target, source ) { /* do on drop */ })
  .on('over', function(el, container, source ) { /* do on over */ })
  .on('out', function(el, container, source ) { /* do on out */ });
```

So basically it does not care if i have the data or not, it just fires the events.
What i'm thinking is to use Rx to limit events to `over` and `out` events until i have data for given draggable item.

My attempt at this:

```
var instance =  dragula(dragulaConfig);
var pauser = new Rx.Subject();
var rxo = Rx.Observable;

var transform = function(el, target, source) {
  return {
    el: el,
    target: target,
    source: source
  };
};

var pause = function() {
  pauser.onNext(false);
};

//subscribe to drag event, and release pause once we have the data./
rxo
.fromEvent(instance, 'drag', transform)
.subscribe(function(event) {
  thisReturnsAPromise(event).then(function() {
    pauser.onNext(true);
  });
});

// subscribe to 'over' event that will not be fired until we have our item data
rxo
.fromEvent(instance, 'over', transform)
.pausable(pauser)
.subscribe(function() { /* show feedback to the user */});

// subscribe to 'out' event that will not be fired until we have our item data
rxo
.fromEvent(instance, 'out', transform)
.pausable(pauser)
.subscribe(function() { /* remove feedback to the user */});

// subscribe to 'cancel' event - this will put pause to over/out events
var cancel = rxo
.fromEvent(instance, 'cancel', transform);
cancel.subscribe(pause);
cancel.subscribe(function() { /* show feedback to the user if he cancels */});

// subscribe to 'drop' event - this will put pause to over/out events
var drop = rxo
.fromEvent(instance, 'drop', transform);
drop.subscribe(pause);
drop.subscribe(function() { /* add dropped item */});
```

Which works, but it just does not feel right (and I'm newbie to RxJS) - too much boilerplate. 
How could I improve this?